# Remove HTTP header on Plone error page

Tags: plone, cache-control

I tried to remove HTTP header for `Cache-Control` on error page of Plone.

I'm using cache setting in Plone control panel, its means added `cache-control` header at all content types. But I want to remove the header on occurred an error. Because I set long time cache for images but I want to set no-cache at an error.

1st try:
I added tag in default_error_message page template.

`dummy_header python:request.RESPONSE.appendHeader('cache-control', '');`

2nd try:

I added command in standard_error_message script.

`context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.setHeader('cache-control', '')`

Please comment or how to fix.

Comment: My suspicion would be that caching, which is later in the processing chain, will step on existing headers. Have you tried setting the value to `no-cache` explicitly to see if that value makes it through?

Comment: I just tried the below: `context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')` . But doesn't work.

Comment: I looked at `plone.caching` and `plone.app.caching`, and there seems to be no (designed) way to ad-hoc mark a page as exempt; plus the caching rules replace existing headers you have already set.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Thank you for your comment. It means we could not fix it, doesn't it?